# Crystal Reports .Net WinForms Viewer - Broken Underlines Using Full Justification

Tags: crystal-reports

When viewing the report in the designer everything looks great, but when I view it via .net WinForms viewer the spaces between words are not underlined.

If i change the alignment from "Justify" To "Align Left", the problem goes away.  We currently use 11.5, I installed 12 trial and still get the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this, but you might look at the "Can Grow" Format setting in Crystal Reports for the object(s) in question. That may or may not fix it, but it's worth a try. Can Grow limits the number of lines the object can grow to, and it will at least go to a new line if it needs to.